# Dual boot for Windows and Linux has gone horribly wrong

Tags: linux, windows, boot, partitioning, multi-boot

I have had a dual boot a few times in the past and have had the configuration that I wanted, but after a few reinstalls I have tried to place the entire system together in an organized manner in on the disks.

This has not been the case this time.  I had a fully installed version of Windows 10 that I had installed on SDA1. It was my assumption that the bootloader was also on SDA.

I found a second boot loader on SDB1. I did some quick testing and it seemed that they both booted into Windows with no issues. I removed the boot sector on SDB and then I installed Windows on SDA in hopes of having a properly functioning dual boot.

I have a properly functioning Linux Mint system now, but it would seem that the Windows bootloader is gone. I am assuming the OS for Windows is in good shape, however.

My questions is, is there a way to install a bootloader in SDA1, along with Windows and Linux, so that I can have a properly functioning dual boot?

I have attached images of the GParted list and below are the results of system inquires.

```
parted --list
[sudo] password for greg: 
Model: ATA TOSHIBA HDWD130 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  101GB   101GB   primary   ntfs
 2      101GB   102GB   472MB   primary   ntfs            diag
 3      102GB   201GB   98.7GB  primary   ext4            boot
 4      201GB   2205GB  2005GB  extended
 5      201GB   201GB   249MB   logical   linux-swap(v1)
 6      201GB   232GB   31.2GB  logical   ext4


Model: ATA SanDisk SD8SBAT2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   Type      File system     Flags
 3      255GB  256GB  899MB  extended
 5      255GB  256GB  899MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)


Model: Linux device-mapper (crypt) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap2: 248MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  248MB  248MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Linux device-mapper (crypt) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 898MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  898MB  898MB  linux-swap(v1)


 inxi -pou
Partition: ID-1: / size: 91G used: 43G (50%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda3
           uuid: 5bbde38b-e7a5-48f9-8bd5-6d5c5bb6c5c8
           ID-2: /home/greg size: 91G used: 43G (50%) fs: ecryptfs dev: /dev/.Private
           uuid: N/A
           ID-3: /media/greg/more size: 29G used: 44M (1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda6
           uuid: 7a2a5b23-5271-41e8-acff-f53d99a48a6b
           ID-4: swap-1 size: 0.90GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-0
           uuid: ba5fa872-9ad3-4de3-8b7f-8c80d3f7f2f4
           ID-5: swap-2 size: 0.25GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-1
           uuid: a1fa6eed-a21a-4ba5-8eaf-5c375b48561e
Unmounted: ID-1: /dev/sda1 size: 101.40G
           label: Windows OS uuid: 32AC5381AC533E93
           ID-2: /dev/sda2 size: 0.47G label: N/A uuid: E6CC5EBBCC5E8629
           ID-3: /dev/sda5 size: 0.25G
           label: N/A uuid: ad3d1b62-a63d-4991-909b-e9d1059b4259
           ID-4: /dev/sdb5 size: 0.90G
           label: N/A uuid: d2bea1e9-bee3-48a2-a881-d69c28b4e23c
```

[image: GParted view]

Comment: updated. Sorry about that.

Comment: You've got a couple of references to links, but no links.  :-)

Comment: Do you already have GRUB with your Linux Mint installation? If not, you can get it from the package manager. That will usually find any operating systems (Even Windows) on the hard disk, and give you an option to boot one or the other like WBM.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution for avoiding dual-boot problems is installing Windows and Linux on separate disks.

1. Remove one disk.
2. Install/repair the OS on disk in computer.

Then exchange disks. Repeat installation/repair for other OS.

After you put back both disks you can choose which disk to boot using "one time boot selection key" (usually F12) from BIOS.